# How to convert the response of an API in a class object

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the Class `SuperHero` and one API consumption that returns a response with the values I wanna create the new SuperHero, but i'm a bit confused about how to do it.

This is my class:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

SuperHero superHeroFromJson(String str) => SuperHero.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String superHeroToJson(SuperHero data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class SuperHero {
    SuperHero({
        this.name,
        this.mainPower,
        this.worstEnemy,
    });

    String name;
    String mainPower;
    String worstEnemy;

    factory SuperHero.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SuperHero(
        name: json["name"],
        mainPower: json["mainPower"],
        worstEnemy: json["worstEnemy"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "mainPower": mainPower,
        "worstEnemy": worstEnemy,
    };
}
```

SuperHeroController

```dart
class SuperHeroController {
  final String hero;

  SuperHeroController({this.hero}){
    loadData(hero);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loadData(String usuario) async {
    final String url = ****;

    final Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = {
      'hero': hero,
    };

    var uri = Uri.parse(url).resolveUri(Uri(queryParameters: queryParams));

    final response = await http.get(
      uri,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    );

    var data = json.decode(response.body);

    print(data);
  }
}
```

My widget

```dart
SuperHero hero;
  SuperHeroController _superHeroController;

  HeroWidget(hero){
    hero = hero;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _heroController = SuperHeroController (hero: Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).id); // getting the user's hero id
  }
```

Running this code, initState is called, it shows in console the structure I have to build in SuperHero class but I don't know how to do it. Where i run the method SuperHeroFromJson in the return and get the object SuperHero with the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _heroController = SuperHeroController(hero: Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).id);
  _loadHero();
}

_loadHero() async {
    hero = await _heroController.loadData();
}
```

and the controller...

```
class SuperHeroController {
  final String hero;

  SuperHeroController({this.hero});

  Future<SuperHero> loadData() async {
    ...
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    return SuperHero.fromJson(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I call hero.name in your loadHero it shows the name, but if I try to write this name in other method to show on screen it throws: `The getter name was called on null`

Comment: It seems like when I open the screen it throws null, but if I hot reload with the error on the screen it shows the name

Comment: have you try setState()?

Comment: Please note that `loadHero()` is an `async` function. Most probably `hero` is not loaded when you try to update its name. Make sure you access `hero` only after it is loaded.